# dominating set of a tournament graph

Tags: graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, tournament

I am writing an algorithm to find the dominating set of a tournament graph. Is the minimum spanning tree of a directed graph equivalent to the dominating set of the graph? In other words, if I find the smallest MST for the tournament graph (by iterating through all of the vertices), can I then say this is equivalent to the dominating set of the graph?

Comment: 'smallest' is redundant in 'smallest MST'. MST is smallest by definition.

Comment: Tournament Dominating Set is [LogSNP-complete](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:L#logsnp) and furthermore [W\[2\]-complete](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:W#w1).  It is unlikely that there is a polynomial time algorithm for Tournament Dominating Set.  However, MST is solvable in polynomial time.  Furthermore, a universal vertex is a dominating set, whereas an MST always has all vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) states that the problems of finding a dominating set and finding a spanning tree are equivalent. Given a spanning tree, the non-leaf nodes form a dominating set, and given a connected dominating set, you can easily obtain of the original graph joining one spanning tree of it with the vertexes that do not belong to it. However, finding a *minimum* spanning tree and finding a *minimal* dominating set are different problems. I guess that they are equivalent again, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not equivalent - Minimum Dominating Set is NP complete, Minimum spanning tree is solvable by Prim's or Kruskal's algorithm, at a cost of O(V^2)

Comment: @Thelema Tournament Dominating Set is not NP-complete, but LogSNP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the MST will include all vertices of the graph, and the dominating set might not.

See for example the graph here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament`_`(graph`_`theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29)
Vertices 2 and 4 create a dominating set, and not a spanning tree.

Comment: I have not yet figured out how to get Wikipedia URLs with parentheses to come out properly in SO.  Any suggestions?